# Huge input lookup on admin orders grid page in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders

Warning: `DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML():` Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup in `/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php` on line `60`

I tried below code but it's not working. can anyone please help me.

```
public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $content
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
        $document = new \DOMDocument(static::XML_VERSION, static::XML_ENCODING);
        $document->loadXML($content, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
        $this->templateNode = $document->documentElement;

    }
public function append($content)
    {
        $target=$this->templateNode->ownerDocument;
        $source = new \DOMDocument();
        $source->loadXml($content, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
        $this->templateNode->appendChild(
            $target->importNode($source->documentElement, TRUE)
        );
    }
```